# How to make this nested for loop about matrices (?) into vectorized code

Tags: r, statistics

I need to make the code below into vectorized code and don't know how to in terms of the easier examples provided to me. Any and all help is appreciated :-)

```
specific_sum_loop <- function(m, pos) {
  my_sum <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
    for (j in pos) {
      my_sum <- my_sum + m[i, j]
    }
  }
  my_sum
}
```

Comment: what is `pos` supposed to be? A vector of positions? If so, what about `sum(m[,pos])`?

Comment: `sum(m[, pos])`

Comment: Mia, one thing Kevin and G are saying is that you are making R very inefficient when their solution is short, fast, and elegant. When you realize that `m[,pos]` returns a vector of the matrix or frame, and `sum` (among many functions) is meant to sum up values within a vector, it's a clean combination.